# Wrapping C# files into a DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll, swig

I have currently used SWIG to convert some C++ libraries that I need to C# to use them a use-case that I am implementing in C#, the output was some CS files that must be included in the project and there is a projectNameBridge.dll file.

Including all these cs in my project is making it looks a bit messy, so I was wondering if there is a way to wrap these CS files in  a DLL that could be a added directly as a reference to contain all these files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can add directories to a solution ...

Comment: I will post a quick dll creation how-to just shortly for you:)

Comment: There you go pictured and explained answer for you:)  Let me know if you need any extra information. I have included an extra preface on compilation targets for dlls as well at the start of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Note regarding DLL compilation

---

Visual studio has at least three compilation targets available (dependant on what you have installed etc):

- `x86` - `x64` - `anycpu`

How these interact and co-habit can be a pain if not done correctly and they behave differently dependant on the bit-count of the OS you are utilising, therefore I have prepended a small, quick guide to how the bitness (for lack of a better term) causes interplay between different setups:

Lets take 3 DLL files, all with the same code in them which we, in true Blue Peter fashion, prepared earlier:

- `anycpu.dll` -- compiled `anycpu`
- `x86.dll` -- compiled `x86`
- `x64.dll` -- compiled `x64`

And 3 executable files all doing the same: calling a console output of "Bitness interplay" from a dll.

- `anycpu.exe` -- compiled `anycpu`
- `x86.exe` -- compiled `x86`
- `x64.exe` -- compiled `x64`

---

The code is identical in all cases however the compilation target has changed, and they work/refuse to work in 32/64 bit OS variants as follows:

### 32-Bit OS

- `anycpu.exe` -- Executes as: 32-bit process DLL Usage: can load
  `anycpu.dll` and `x86.dll` Causes `BadImageFormatException` if it tries to
  load `x64.dll`
- `x86.exe` -- Executes as: 32-bit process DLL Usage: can load `anycpu.dll`
  and `x86.dll` Causes `BadImageFormatException` if it tries to load
  `x64.dll`
- `x64.exe` -- Executes as: `BadImageFormatException` when it tries to run

### 64-Bit OS

- `anycpu.exe` -- Executes as: 64-bit process DLL Usage: can load
  `anycpu.dll` and `x64.dll` Causes `BadImageFormatException` if it tries to
  load `x86.dll`
- `x86.exe` -- Executes as: 32-bit process DLL Usage: can load `anycpu.dll`
  and `x86.dll` Causes `BadImageFormatException` if it tries to load
  `x64.dll
- `x64.exe` -- Executes as: 64-bit process DLL Usage: can load `anycpu.dll`
  and `x64.dll` Causes `BadImageFormatException` if it tries to load
  `x86.dll`

So, unless you truly need a certain Bitness/bitlyness (there is no nice word for it!) I would stick to the `anycpu` compilation target: its a little less perfect than specific targeting but your creation should do you proud regardless of the flavour of bits (there that's a nicer way to say it) you happen to be running on.

---

### Important:

My brother made a good point that bears mentioning: some SDKs require a particular compilation target (ANYCPU, x84, x64 etc) and utilising the wrong one can cause compile-/run-time errors.

---

## Start the project

To create a DLL file in C# is even more straightforward than in C++:
Firstly we create a new project, based on the class library type

[image: Starting a dll project]

After having set the relative parameters of your choice and subsequently hitting the "OK" button we are just about done, as VS neatly brings us into the C# file you specified in the previous screen.

May as well add some code to perform the actions we require the DLL to be able to carry out...

[image: Let's go!]

Now that the code is in place, you can build the project using Release or Debug mode (whichever suits your needs most closely).

[image: Build the DLL]

Navigate to the relevant build folder.....
[image: Navigate to the relevant folder]
Et Voila! your shiny new DLL is ready to use!

And now you can call the DLL from another C# project at your leisure:)

---

Hope this helps, and, let me know if you need any more information:)

Comment: woah, thats a lot of info

Comment: "Bitness/bitlyness (there is no nice word for it!)" - its called "CPU Architecture"; its also worth noting that for some SDKs selecting anything other than ANY CPU will cause compile-time/runtime errors (SharePoint 2010 and above).

Comment: True, will add that part in:)

Answer (score 2):

Put them into separate project with output type of "Class library"?